# bundle install --without production error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant

here is my part of my log help please(new to vagrant)

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ bundle install --without production
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-linux/1.9.1/json-1.8.1 (Errno::EACCES)`
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
        ......
        ......
```

Comment: what? you can not just dump a log file here and expect people to magic up a solution for you.

Comment: pardon am new to stack overflow, i will improve, please look at the first few lines

Comment: It's not hard really, just work out exactly what your question is and then ask it.

Comment: On behalf of @Zen "Can you provide a bit more information? When you launch this command are you using the same user used during ruby installation? Has your user the necessary permission to write on that folder? Because the error seems caused by a failed mkdir -p command (creation of a folder with the sub folder included)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried running `sudo bundle install`? It looks like there is a permissions issue...

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-linux/1.9.1/json-1.8.1 (Errno::EACCES)`
```

Comment: @user3197544 - you could always accept the answer :)